# How to get stream from Google+ REST API using python?

Tags: python, streaming, google-plus

I have been browsing the Google Plus APIs and I can't seem to figure out if its possible to get the stream of posts(feed) of all those people who I have circled.

I have read through the Google+ API documentation and even tried Google's API explorer, but couldn't seem to figure out how to do it.

It's a very important feature of any API, which really shouldn't be missing to stream automatically on my page.

Comment: What does it have to do with Python ???

Comment: just i want to create google + feed on my webpage using python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/list.

`GET https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me/people/connected`

```
import requests
import json

r = requests.get('https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me/people/connected')

input_log = json.loads(r.text)
```

Comment: With this things when i request that times get some json data but without doing this its possible ?

Comment: Can you explain more, what you posted doesn't really make sense?

Comment: Dear i want the data of my google + activity with streaming API thats my problem how can i do ?

Comment: What have you tried?  This site/community likes to see code you have tried first.